# map function that returns numerical 0 or 1 for true or false

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary

I'm trying to count the number of vowels in a string by splitting the string into an array of letters and then map vowel letters to `1` and summing up the array.

```
def count_vowels(string)
    vowels = ['a','e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    return string.split("").map{ |n| vowels.include? n ? 1 : 0}.inject(0,:+)
end
```

The `include?` part doesn't correctly return `1` or `0`. Any suggestion why this won't fly?

I hacked it to this version which works, but looks kind of foolish:

```
def count_vowels(string)
    vowels = ['a','e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    return string.split("").map{ |n| vowels.include? n}.inject(0) do |mem,x|
        x ? mem + 1 : mem
    end
end
```

Comment: `string.count("aeiou")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason:

```
string.split("").map{ |n| vowels.include? n ? 1 : 0}.inject(0,:+)
```

does not work is because `n ? 1 : 0` is evaluated and passed as an argument to `include?` instead of `n`. You need to add some parentheses in `include?`:

```
string.split("").map{ |n| vowels.include?(n) ? 1 : 0}.inject(0,:+)
```

You can simply do

```
def count_vowels(string)
  vowels = ['a','e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  string.split(//).select { |x| vowels.include? x }.length
end
```

Comment: Good explanation. Re the revised method I suggest: 1 `each_char` rather than `split(//)`, 2. `count` rather than `select/length` and 3. @steenslag's suggestion rather than my #1 and #2.

Comment: I am going to say what I am saying on almost every such question involving the condit ional operator: just use `if` instead, it has the precedence you expect and is more readable: `if vowels.include? n then 1 else 0 end`. Of course, adding the parentheses is a good idea anyway (and recommended by most style guides).

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for the suggestion I literally started messing around with Ruby today so I didn't figure out all the syntax yet. I knew the tertiary operator from js so just brought it over and worked out perfectly. You are correct the explicit keywords are more readable

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `map`.

```
def count_vowels(string)
  vowels = %w[a e i o u]
  string.chars.select{|n| vowels.include? n}.size
end
```

Comment: You don't even need `select`.
`string.each_char.count { |c| vowels.include? c }` will do :-D

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need parantheses for `include?` method parameter. So

```
return string.split("").map{ |n| vowels.include?(n) }.inject(0) do |mem,x|
```

Anyway, your code might be better

- `VOWELS = %w(a e i o u) # string's array`
- you don't need return in your method, it's the last statement
- `string.split("")` => `string.chars`

Note that your method could be so:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  string.count "aeiou"
end
```